# Change magento transactional emails logo_url to external link

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I need to change

> logo_url

for transactional emails with external link, for example

> https://exampledomainname.com/image.png

but I can't hardcode all or even one file in

> app/locale

Is there any way to add external url as logo_url? As when I go here:

> System > Configuration > General > Design > Transactional Emails

I can only add image to hosting area

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was looking into the web there is no `best practice` way to directly rewrite `logo_url`, but we can create custom variable and then use it into email templates. We can do it manually from admin or using programming way. My requirements is to implement this in programming way, so we start with shell script(`shell\external_logo_url.php`) to create custom variable:

```
<?php    

require_once '../abstract.php';

class External_Logo_Url extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        $variable = Mage::getModel('core/variable')
            ->setCode('variable-code')
            ->setName('variable-name')
            ->setPlainValue('variable-value')
            ->save();
    }
}

$shell = new External_Logo_Url();
$shell->run();
```

Also we need to change template files in `app\locale`, so you need replace **all** template files or **custom** templates that you need. You should look for `{{var logo_url}}` and replace with `{{customVar code=variable-code}}`.